# What does one have to know about The Darkness to enjoy the story in The Darkness II?

Tags: the-darkness-2

If one wanted to play "The Darkness II" without playing its prequel, "The Darkness", what would they need to know about the story in order to not miss anything important?

Small references and easter eggs do not count, I'm asking for important information relevant to the events of the second game.

Comment: You can get the first game for like 6 bucks. It's worth picking up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you watch the following movie, it sums up the basics of the first game's concept to bring you up to speed:

I don't think you need to know too much about the first game to enjoy the second one. You can always read [the plot section in the game's Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Darkness_%28video_game%29#Plot) if you wish to know everything that happened in the first game.